# If $x$ and $y$ are solitary numbers satisfying $\gcd(x,y)=1$, under what conditions does it follow that $xy$ is also solitary?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $\sigma(z)$ denote the sum of divisors of $z \in \mathbb{N}$.  Denote the abundancy index of $z$ by $I(z) = \sigma(z)/z$.

If the equation $I(z)=I(a)$ has the lone solution $z=a$, then $a$ is said to be *solitary*.  Greening's Theorem states that if $\gcd(b,\sigma(b))=1$, then $b$ is solitary.  (Note that the converse does not necessarily hold.)

Here is my question:

> If $x$ and $y$ are solitary numbers satisfying $\gcd(x,y)=1$, under what conditions does it follow that $xy$ is also solitary?

The latest paper on solitary numbers that I could find on Google seems to be [New families of solitary numbers](https://doi.org/10.1142/S0219498815400046) by Paul A. Loomis.  However, my present inquiry is not covered in this paper.

Comment: Given how little is known about solitary numbers (e.g., it's not even known whether 10 is solitary), I don't hold out much hope for an insightful answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

Note that all prime numbers are solitary.

**Claim 1** : If $x=3$ and $y$ is a prime of the form $6k+1$, then $xy$ is solitary.

*Proof* :  We get $\sigma(xy)=\sigma(3y)=(1+3)(1+6k+1)=8(3k+1)$, so
$$\gcd(xy,\sigma(xy))=\gcd(3(6k+1),8(3k+1))=\gcd(6k+1,3k+1)=1$$
It follows that $xy$ is solitary. $\quad\blacksquare$

**Claim 2** : If $x=5$ and $y$ is a prime of the form $10k+3$ where $k\ge 1\in\mathbb N$, then $xy$ is solitary.

*Proof* : We get $\sigma(xy)=\sigma(5y)=(1+5)(1+10k+3)=12(5k+2)$, so
$$\gcd(xy,\sigma(xy))=\gcd(5(10k+3),12(5k+2))=\gcd(10k+3,5k+2)=1$$
It follows that $xy$ is solitary. $\quad\blacksquare$

**Claim 3** : If $x=5$ and $y$ is a prime of the form $10k+7$, then $xy$ is solitary.

*Proof* : We get $\sigma(xy)=\sigma(5y)=(1+5)(1+10k+7)=12(5k+4)$, so
$$\gcd(xy,\sigma(xy))=\gcd(5(10k+7),12(5k+4))=\gcd(10k+7,5k+4)=1$$
It follows that $xy$ is solitary. $\quad\blacksquare$

---

**Added** : From Erick Wong's comment, I've got some examples.

**Claim** : If $x$ is a prime such that $x\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $y$ is a prime of the form $2x(x+1)k+x-2$, then $xy$ is solitary.

*Proof* : We get
$$\gcd(x,\sigma(y))=\gcd(x,x(2kx+2k+1)-1)=1$$
and
$$\gcd(\sigma(x),y)=\gcd(x+1,(x+1)(2kx+1)-3)=1$$
It follows that $xy$ is solitary. $\quad\blacksquare$

**P.S.** : Since $\gcd(2x(x+1),x-2)=\gcd(x-2,12)=1$ for $x\equiv 1\pmod 3$, there are, by Dirichlet's theorem, infinitely many primes of the form $2x(x+1)k+x-2$.

Some examples for small $x$ :

- If $x=7$ and $y$ is a prime of the form $112k+5$, then $xy$ is solitary.
- If $x=13$ and $y$ is a prime of the form $364k+11$, then $xy$ is solitary.
- If $x=19$ and $y$ is a prime of the form $760k+17$, then $xy$ is solitary.
- If $x=31$ and $y$ is a prime of the form $1984k+29$, then $xy$ is solitary.

Comment: If $x = 5$ and $y$ is a prime number of the form $3k + 2$ for $k \geq 0$ and $k \neq 1$, does it follow that $\gcd(xy, \sigma(xy))=1$?

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris : No, it doesn't. For $y=29$, we have $\gcd(xy,\sigma(xy))=\gcd(145,180)=5$.

Comment: Okay, thanks again @mathlove. I will wait for some more days and will accept your answer if there are no others. =)

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Note that these all fall under the umbrella of “if $x,y$ are coprime solitary numbers and $(x,\sigma(y)) = (\sigma(x),y)=1$ then $xy$ is solitary”.  The answer provides some concrete infinite families which meet this criterion.

Comment: @Erick Wong : From your comment, I've got some examples.

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris : I've added some examples.

Comment: @mathlove:  Thank you for your comprehensive answer!  Gladly accepting your answer now.  =)